# I need a textbox value in form 1 to be inserted into form2 as a string in the html level in asp

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I would like to 'transfer' a textbox value into a html code. E.g the textbox value is a website like http://www.google.com in form1.aspx. and i would like the value to be put into the html code in form2.aspx . Might i ask how i should be going around on this?

```
<span class="logoposition">
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="Logo.jpg" height= "120"; width="280"; /></a>
</span>
```

Like i would like the textbox1 value to replace the current www.google.com

Comment: You can try an anchor tag with `runat="server"` attribute in form2.aspx. From page1 redirect to page2 with text value in query string. Parse the request.querystring in page2 and set it as href of the anchor.

Comment: Could you show an example of your suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this:

**Webform1 Markup:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="SOTest1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>   
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>            
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Your text: ">
                </asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="GO" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Webform1 Code:**

```
using System;

namespace SOTest1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myString = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text);
            Response.Redirect("Webform2.aspx?mystring=" + myString);
        }
    }
}
```

**Webform2 Markup:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="SOTest1.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <span class="logoposition">
        <a href="http://www.google.com" runat="server" id="myAnchor"><img src="Logo.jpg" height= "120"; width="280"; /></a>
    </span>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Webform2 Code:**

```
using System;

namespace SOTest1
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string mystring = Request.QueryString["mystring"];
            myAnchor.HRef = mystring;
            myAnchor.InnerText = mystring;
        }
    }
}
```